# For matrices $A$ and $B$, $B-A\succeq 0$ (i.e. psd) implies $\text{Tr}(B)\geq \text{Tr}(A)$ and $\det(B)\geq\det(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $B$ and $A$ are symmetric matrices of the same dimensions.

**Claim**: $B-A\succeq 0$ implies $\text{Tr}(B)\geq \text{Tr}(A)$ and $\det(B)\geq\det(A)$

**Attempt**: Let $C=B-A$, then $C$ has nonnegative eigenvalues so that 
$$
0\leq\text{Tr}(C)=\text{Tr}(B)-\text{Tr}(A)\implies \text{Tr}(B)\geq \text{Tr}(A).
$$
I don't know how to proceed with the second claim.

The context of this claim is that $A$ and $B$ are covariance matrices so maybe we need to assume that they both are positive semidefinite. But even with that, I'm still stuck.

Thank you very much!

Comment: $B-A\ge 0$ implies that $\lambda_j(B)\ge\lambda_j(A)$ (by the min-max principle).

Comment: @Kim Jong Un: you want to add $B\succeq 0$ for the $\det$ part

Comment: @ Christian Rembling and orangeskid: thank you for your interest. @ Christian Rembling: I'm not familiar with the min-max principle. If you have time, please elaborate as an answer below.

Comment: @KimJongUn: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Min-max_Theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you need $A\succeq0$, otherwise your claim isn't true (e.g. when $B=-I_2$ and $A=-2I_2$).

Suppose $B\succeq A\succeq0$, then for any $\epsilon>0$, we have $B+\epsilon I\succeq A+\epsilon I\color{red}{\succ}0$ and hence
$$
(A+\epsilon)^{-1/2}(B+\epsilon)(A+\epsilon)^{-1/2}\succeq I\succ0.
$$
Therefore all eigenvalues of $(A+\epsilon)^{-1/2}(B+\epsilon)(A+\epsilon)^{-1/2}$ are at least 1. You may continue from here.

Comment: +1 for $A\succeq 0$ and for the approach. Your approach also inspired my own answer!

Answer (score 1):

My approach is similar to that of [user1551](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1551/user1551), perhaps a bit more pedestrian.

As above let $C=B-A$. As noted by user1551, it is necessary to assume that $A\succeq 0$. If it is *not* the case that $A\succ 0$, then $\det(A)=0$ so that $\det(B)\geq 0=\det(A)$ holds trivially. So let us assume $A\succ 0$. This allows us to define: 
$$
D=A^{-1/2}CA^{-1/2}. 
$$
Because $C$ is psd, $D$ is also psd and thus has nonnegative eigenvalues. This means $I+D$ has eigenvalues that are no less than $1$ so we have $\det(I+D)\geq 1$. Now our claim follows:
$$
B=A+C=A^{1/2}(I+D)A^{1/2}\implies\det(B)=\det(A)\det(I+D)\geq\det(A).
$$